# How do you pass more than one variable to a gtk signal handler?

Tags: gtk, signals

I was told the only/best way to do this is to store the variables in a struct and pass the struct, however it's turned into a gpointer and I can't seem to be able to turn it back into a struct to retrieve the data.

If there is any other way I would like to use that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your struct back to the proper type in your signal handler.

```
MyVariables *vars = (MyVariables *)user_data;
```

**PS**. Oh, yeah, and don't forget to allocate your struct; if you pass a local variable, it will have disappeared by the time your signal handler is called.

Comment: When I try something like this is says `error: ‘MyVariables’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: `MyVariables` isn't the name of anything, it's the type name of your struct. You _did_ do `typedef struct { GtkWidget *whatever; } MyVariables;`, right?

Comment: No `typedef`, that should fix it.

Comment: Ok, seems to work. I presume I still have to `free` the structs at the end of memory? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can supply a function for freeing your data parameter when the signal is disconnected; see the documentation for [`g_signal_connect_data()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-data). I'm not 100% sure, but I think `g_signal_connect_data(object, "signal-name", G_CALLBACK(signal_handler), vars, g_free, 0);` should work.